tikz: smaller output sizes for many repeated circles?
I am trying to make a few graphs to include in other documents in tikz.  Because the renderers take time (and probably aren't very clever), image size matters.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  %% 4,000 circles
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,40} {
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,100} {
      \draw[fill=red] (40+\x,10+\y) circle [radius=0.3];
    }
  }

  %% to have something else
  \node[scale=60, rotate=-30] at (20,150) { Aladdin's Lamp };
  \draw[dashed] (60,65) ellipse (35 and 75);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The resulting document is 300K.  Converting into png at a reasonable resolution is even larger.  I have tried to experiment with patterns to speed this up, but I tend to run into overflows (some dimensions or counters or ... that are being exceeded).  Maybe generating svg would be a good idea.  not sure.
how should I approach this?  advice appreciated.
/iaw

What's the purpose of showing 4000 circles? What is it good for?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{circles}
{\pgfpoint{-1}{-1}}{\pgfpoint{1}{1}}{\pgfpoint{1}{1}}
{
 \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.3}
 \pgfsetlinewidth{0.02}
 \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
 \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=circles, pattern color=red] (40pt,10pt) rectangle (80pt,110pt); 
\node[scale=1.5, rotate=-30] at (20pt,150pt) {Aladdin's Lamp};
\draw[dashed] (60pt,65pt) ellipse[x radius=35pt, y radius=75pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




which has the astonishing size of 14K!!!1. thanks.  now I have to study further why my attempts always died.

You can use grid.

\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick, dash pattern=on 0mm off 10mm, line cap=round, double=red, double distance=6mm](40,10)grid(80,110);
  %% to have something else
  \node[scale=60, rotate=-30] at (20,150) { Aladdin's Lamp };
  \draw[dashed] (60,65) ellipse (35 and 75);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


how clever getting circles from line caps!
